# javascript not working form.textid.indexOf("")

Tags: indexof

I have this code and it worked for a few minutes. However I reloaded my page and now I cannot get it to work and I cannot figure out why. Any help would be much appreciated.
Code:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="test">
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="check(this.form)">

<script lang="JavaScript">
function check(form) {
    if (form.test.indexOf("yes")) {
        alert("play sound");

        }
        else {

        alert("no sound");

    }
}
</script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tested your code in Google Chrome's Javascript console, I got Typeerror: cannot read property 'test' of undefined. It looks like you're trying to validate the user input in the input box, but whatever value entered needs to be referenced in your code before finding the string segment of that string with the indexOf ().

Here's a `jsFiddle` of showing you how to get the user input value with jQuery. 
Use jQuery's val() method or Javascript's value() method to get the user input, then you can use indexOf method to find the string segments

```
    var arr=["random","Javascript","donuts","closures"];
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               var userInput=$("#userInput").val();
               if($.inArray(userInput,arr) != -1){
                  alert("success");
               }
           })
        });
```